# TextChanged in Xamarin like in WPF?

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, textchanged

For a project I need to send live textes while the user is typing. To not send all the text, which is in an Entry I created a protocol which sends only the changes of the text. Like this:
Initial (Old) Text: `Hello`
New Text: `ello World` protocol sends: `+[5][ World]-[0][1]` where + means adding, - means removing, 5 means at position 5, 0 means at position 0 and 1 means remove one character.

To archive this in WPF I wrote this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{    
    foreach (var change in e.Changes)
    {
        if (change.RemovedLength > 0)
        {
            lcb.Remove((byte)change.Offset, (byte)change.RemovedLength);
        }
        if (change.AddedLength > 0)
        {
            var lul = WriteText.Substring(change.Offset, change.AddedLength);
            lcb.Add((byte)change.Offset, lul);
        }
    }
}
```

In Xamarin `TextChangedEventArgs` only implements `.NewTextValue` and `.OldTextvalue` so working with `.Changes` doesn't work here anymore.

Is there a 'Hack' or something to get the characters which were changed like in WPF or do I have to work with algorithms like [O(ND) Difference Algorithm](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13326/An-O-ND-Difference-Algorithm-for-C) and manually get the changes?

Comment: hi, what appens if user select all text and replace it with paste command?

Comment: @GiancarloMelis: On WPF `RemovedLength` would be the length of the Old Text and `AddedLength` would be the length of the new text. On Xamarin `OldTextValue` would be the old text and `NewTextValue` would be the new value, why you ask?